# Will Session be expired by IdleTimeout of IIS?

Tags: asp.net, session, iis

I have `<sessionState cookieless="false" mode="InProc" timeout="120" />` in my web.config.

But looks like session is expired by IIS Idle timeout which is 20 minutes.

I can't change Idle Timeout manually in IIS, because I have a lot of instances. Can I change it via code or .config files?

Or maybe it's not actually the reason of session expiration?

Answer (score 0):

> When these settings are configured, a worker process will shut down after a specified period of inactivity

, from [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771956(v=ws.10).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

InProc means a session is tracked by a cached record in process memory. Thus, whenever the process exits (with exceptions or not), that session is gone.

Then of course idle timeout of IIS matters in your case, as it can shut down the worker process, and in turn kill the sessions.